# Is "play it safe" informal register?

Tags: idioms, formality, register

On a rather formal ecommerce website I am talking about safety features a product has which competitors are lacking. The customer is considered business-like, and not as a buddy.

> Play it safe. [Our product does ...]

Can I use this phrase in the given context, or is it too informal?

Comment: The expression is not formal, but effective: https://www.paf.com/about/play-it-safe.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others said, it's pretty informal (though not prohibitively so), but I think the way you structured your copy makes it OK.

In your case it sounds like a self-contained pithy slogan that introduces the subject of security:

> Play it safe. Our product's security features...

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely a more informal/conversational phrase than you'd want for a business website.

Also, I'm not sure it would be accurate for what you want to describe. 'Play it safe' either means 'cautious' or 'not daring' e.g.

The film plays it safe, sticking with the usual tropes of a thriller rather than trying something original. (not daring)

Our flight was at 10pm - so we played it safe and arrived at 6.30pm. (cautious/careful)

It doesn't really have a connotation related to 'safety' in the way that I think you are talking about.